# Chartjs display label & units when mouse is hover stats

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, label, chart.js

Is it possible to have the label & units when my mouse pointer is hover the chart ? For now there is only the number.

For the example bellow I would like to show :

- 58% Label1
- 0% Label2
- 0% Label3
- 0% Label4
- 0% Label5

[image]

My options looks like this :

```
var options = {
      //Boolean - Show a backdrop to the scale label
      scaleShowLabelBackdrop : true,
      //Boolean - Whether to show labels on the scale
      scaleShowLabels : true,
      // Boolean - Whether the scale should begin at zero
      scaleBeginAtZero : true,
      scaleLabel : "<%%= Number(value) + ' %'%>",
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><%% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%%=datasets[i].strokeColor%>\"></span><%%if(datasets[i].label){%><%%=datasets[i].label%> <strong><%%=datasets[i].value%></strong><%%}%></li><%%}%></ul>",
      tooltipTemplate: "<%%= value %> Label"
    }
```

With scaleLabel option I have the % shown on the Y-axis but not on the hover pop-up...

Comment: anything is possible. Where is the code you have tried?

Comment: @tellez the options I tried is on the post, this is where it is supposed to be right ? I don't find on the doc the options to changes the display of the **popup**, all I found is about the scale

Comment: @tellez I found that the options that might be usefull is tooltipTemplate, but when I change it, nothing happens on my chart...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the solution [on the ChartJS repository on Github](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/535#issuecomment-52075422).

The solution is to use the option `multiTooltipTemplate` **if your graph has multiple data**. Otherwise, you should use `tooltipTemplate`

```
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%=datasetLabel%> : <%= value %>"  // Regular use
// or
multiTooltipTemplate: "<%%=datasetLabel%> : <%%= value %>"  // Ruby on Rails use
```

Will give you :

- Dataset_label : value

Comment: Thanks soooo much! :-D

Comment: Glad it helped you ;)

Comment: Thanks. but I got an error upon using <%%=, so I followed the link you shared and in that I found it like <%= and it worked.

Comment: <%%= doesn't work, I edited the Post to <%=, why did you change it back? @StéphaneJ.

Comment: @Daidon I've edited my post and answer and added a tag. Sorry, it was not clear at all but this was a solution for Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one, it will work. You just need to check what's the data coming in the label function.

```
options: {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      title: function() {
        return "";
      },
      label: function(item, data) {
        var datasetLabel = data.datasets[item.datasetIndex].label || "";
        var dataPoint = item.yLabel;
        return datasetLabel + ": " + dataPoint + "min";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check the formatting of your answer.

Comment: excellent , Thank you for help  , In my case I used constant bar height but want to display different value on hover . This code resolve my issue .